# ROS_INFO on rosserial?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does rosserial support ROS_INFO?

I tried using it, but the compile failed.  I can see why this might be, as there is no "console" for output.

If so, is there a library or something to add?

If not, is there a way to send out a message other than standard publish?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11227/ros_info-on-rosserial?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can do ROS_INFO, but not with the same kind of syntax.

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Logging

You also need to be using rosserial from source in order to use this.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2011-09-16**:
oops, missed that doc.  Thanks for the help.